# How to grab UUID from Firefox/Chrome add-on/extenstion

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am trying to grab the uuid that is assigned to each extenstion/add-on installation. This is not  the extension ID that is that same across all extension installations. This is the one that is unique for each user per install.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can call `browser.runtime.getURL('/');` this will return you a url string like `moz-extension://9a08sd798-af1b-4572-95ab-9d6866517ade/` then you can parse the string from that or if you need it to open a tab to your popup just put the url to your popup.

```
let url = browser.runtime.getURL('/dist/frontend/index.html');
browser.tabs.create({
  url
})
```